# Command not found NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ubuntu-12.04, ndk-build

I am using ubuntu and  trying to build a project  and I am using the following code:

```
cd <project-directory>/tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path .
ant release
```

When I type ndk-build it returns command not found.
It returns command not found.I extracted the ndk bin file and made it a folder. Please help me out.

Comment: Need NDK full path Try this : 

  project-directory>D:\android-ndk\ndk-build

Answer (score 2):

You must include in your PATH variable the path to the android NDK. For example, on my machine, I have, in my `.zshrc` (could be in `.bashrc` for you), the following line:

> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-ndk

Then enter the command `bash` to restart your shell, and the command should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  If you have not done so already, you must first download NDK from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download

Once you've done that, follow the steps to execute the package so that the NDK extracts itself.  Once it is extracted, perform the following:

`export PATH=/<your_path_to_the_ndk>:$PATH`

This will add directly to your path.  Also make sure to add the Android SDK Tools and Platform-tools to the path by performing `export PATH=/<path_to_tools_or_platform-tools>/:$PATH`

That should be all you need.  You can now navigate to the tess-two folder and perform `ndk-build`